# Author's nodes page with Views

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I have a site where there can be more than one node author. My solution to this is a custom user reference field called *additional authors*, added to my content type. So if three people wrote an article, the person who publishes it, enters the other two into this *additional authors* field.

The problem I have is the following:
I'm trying to create a page (with Views) with the listing of all author's nodes - these can be either nodes where he is author **OR** nodes where he is referenced under additional authors. I want the author to be specified in the url (mysite.com/people/john-smith), but if I use contextual filters in Views, I can't seem to find the option to use OR - e.g. take author ID from url and show nodes where he is author of OR nodes where he is under additional authors.

Comment: Call a php function in arguments and return all node ids seperated by comma in that.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate? I've mostly used just the WYSIWYG portion of Views.

Comment: I don't think you can do that. At least without writing your own Views filter handler. Could you switch to having all authors populate that author field? This is what I have done before, using Rules to automate the process of adding yourself to the authors field if you're missing.

Comment: Okay this might sound really strange, but have you checked the search_api module + db_search_api backend? you would index the articles node types author and ref fields and then create a view based on the search index where you add a contextual filter that uses the name. I used a similar technique when I needed all articles that featured a name in the text shown as a table.

Comment: I can give you example of such work that I have done in past, I can give you a screencast or a link to blog. I will create one if I don't find in a day. http://www.rapwars.com, this is not yet live but one of the site, where I have used such stuff in internal listing pages

Comment: Tobias: my god, of course, how did I not see that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any problem here:?? why you don't add the 'authors field' to your fields?
If you don't find it by the normal way look for it in 'Relationships'
Goodluck